# Div with a fieldset aligned to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a little bit of problem, that I can't seem to quite figure out on my own.

How can I have a 100% width container div that has a fieldset and input box aligned to the right, it seems that my current result is that the groupbox overrides my desired div width and thus stretches it 100% in the pic:
[image]

This is my desired result:
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<div style="width: 100%;">

    <div style="width: auto; text-align: right;">

        <fieldset style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);">
            <legend style="color: rgb(11,63,113); font-weight: bold; font-size: 11pt;">File Number</legend>
            <input type="text" id="fileno" style="background: white url(images/glass.png) left no-repeat; padding-left: 19px;" onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event,this)">
        </fieldset>

    </div>


</div>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your fieldset is block-level and so 100% wide by default. Give it a fixed width, float it, or change its display to inline-block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to apply a width element to the field set element and float it to the right.

```
<div style="width: 100%;">

    <div style="width: auto; text-align: right; border: 1px solid red; height: 75px;">

        <fieldset style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128) width: 200px; float: right">
            <legend style="color: rgb(11,63,113); font-weight: bold; font-size: 11pt;">File Number</legend>
            <input type="text" id="fileno" style="background: white url(images/glass.png) left no-repeat; padding-left: 19px;" onkeydown="handleKeyDown(event,this)">
        </fieldset>

    </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2KydL/) using your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of solutions.  The main issue is that the inner div is `display: block` and creates an entire block (takes up the entire width even with `width: auto`.  One possibility is to change it to `display: inline-block`.  You can also use `text-align: right` on the outer div to have it on the right side like you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/At63D/

You could also `float: right` the inner div, but you would have to apply a clearfix to the outer div.